# Name mismatch on airline ticket/insurance

Tags: tickets, airlines, international-travel, insurance, paperwork

I have a group booking done by an Indian provider for my trip to Europe. 
The booking is on Qatar Airways for me and my wife. Now there is an issue with the booking name for the ticket and insurance.

Actually what happened was that both of us had got new passports (after adding of spouse name), but the Indian provider by mistake booked as per the details against old passport.

So for the ticket;

- My name is same in both old/new passport (First Middle Last)
- My wife has the name printed as First Last...which are the same in both old/new (but the new passport also has the middle name)
- The insurance has more visible details from the old passport (like passport number, address..again my wife has a different address in the new passport)

Can these cause any major issues at the airport?
I have already asked the travel operator to send me the updated ticket/insurance as per the new passport.
But I was just wondering if they could not for some reasons...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I travel within US if name on ticket is abbreviated?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23417/can-i-travel-within-us-if-name-on-ticket-is-abbreviated)

Comment: As for the ticket it is a duplicate, you may center your question on the insurance part.

Answer (score 2):

The guys and girls at the check-in desk are allowed a certain level of tolerance. I know that for misspelled names one wrong letter is allowed.

A "forgotten" middle name is usually not a problem either. I know of a couple of cases where did not have their middle names on their tickets and this didn't matter at all.

Only if the names look very different they will have a closer look (call their supervisor) and potentially deny boarding.