# Middle name missing on flight reservation, can I still fly?

Tags: air-travel, planning, airlines, bookings

As per passport my name is Manish Kumar Ahuja, but by mistake I book a ticket with the name of Manish Ahuja. My middle name is not on the ticket. Can I fly on this ticket? Because the airline can't add the name and they say that the ticket is non-refundable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My last name is not the same on ticket as on passport; rest of details are same](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22088/my-last-name-is-not-the-same-on-ticket-as-on-passport-rest-of-details-are-same)

Comment: When you say "the airline can't add the name", it sounds like you've already spoken to them about this. Why didn't you ask the airline this question during that conversation?

Answer (score 14):

Missing a middle name is usually not a problem when flying, because many people commonly omit their middle names when booking as well. Since the first and last names are correct, you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: Depends on the country. In USA, it is a big problem.

Comment: @PeterMasiar I have taken a number of flights in the US, and I've never used my middle names when doing so. I've yet to have a problem.

Answer (score 2):

The "ticket" you have is just a reference to a booking that you have made. The Check-In staff will print your Boarding Pass for the airplane as long your "ticket" name matches your passport name.

Ask the person on the Check-in desk to print your full name on the Boarding Pass. If you run into someone from Security who objects to the name on your Boarding Pass it is usually quite simple to get the name changed. (Although it may mean a trip back to the Check-In desk.)

I have a middle name and previously this has been left off, as well as my first name being abbreviated. This has occasionally caused problems with the TSA. I now always check my Boarding Pass and request the name to be changed to better match my passport name if needed.

This is quite similar to : [Can I travel within US if name on ticket is abbreviated?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23417/can-i-travel-within-us-if-name-on-ticket-is-abbreviated/)

Answer (score -1):

This might be a real problem if flying **to or from USA.** APIS requires valid middle name. Examples: https://www.aa.com/i18n/travel-info/security/secure-flight.jsp

Middle name has to be **exactly** as in your passport.

Full disclosure: I work for a company providing flight services, including flights to and from USA. Mismatched middle name is daily recurring problem. All the downvoters based they vote on wishful thinking, how the situation should be. I write as situation **is**.

Comment: The data used for APIS will be collected during check-in.  There is no requirement to have a middle name listed on the ticket for APIS/TSA/etc.

Comment: I routinely fly into and out of the US without including the middle name listed in my passport. As Doc pointed out, the name on your ticket is irrelevant to APIS.